# How do you create a report from the smartsheet API?

Tags: smartsheet-api

In particular, I am using the python SDK to endeavor to create a report.  I can copy and modify sheets.  However, via the API, I haven't figured out how to create a report.  Any suggestions / sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the API doesn't support creating reports.
If you would describe your scenario, it would help us prioritize this feature.